# Как найти программу на сервере, которая посылает tcp запросы

Tags: php, linux, apache, tcp

Имеем сервер с проектом подключенным к платежным системам. Над проектом трудятся 4 разработчика.

На днях обнаружил, что с одной из платежных систем деньги уходят на сторонние адреса, хотя в бд проекта нет записей об этих переводах.

Получается, что на сервере запущен (или запускается по крону) какой-то скрипт, который ворует деньги.

Отключил вывод для пользователей на сайте. Деньги все равно переводятся. Решил отключить API в кабинерте платежной системы.

`tcpdump` ловит запросы на сервер платежной системы, с периодичностью 10-20 минут.

Исходящие порты всегда разные, значит скорее всего это апач. В кодах проекта искал по тексту, ничего не нашел. Скорее всего код обфусцирован.

Как можно найти программу, если только знаем что она периодически отправляет запросы на определенный адрес? Крон отключать нельзя, ибо продакшн :(

Comment: Если по крону, посмотрите задачи крона, найдите ту, которая запускает скрипт, запросы идут на одни и те же адреса?

Comment: Если исходящие порты разные, то это не `скорее всего апач`, а любое клиентское соединение. В момент, когда запускается запрос на сайт платежной системы, запускаете `netstat` и смотрите, по номеру порта, что это за процесс

Comment: Sysdig вам в помощь

Comment: Igor Lavrynenko, какой скрипт? Я об это и спрашиваю.
Anton Shchyrov, очень сложно это сделать, на сервере 200+ запросов в секунду.
linuxoid69, спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Есть *ss*, есть *netstat -nap -t* и много разных утилит, но проблема у вас в трёх буквах: PHP. (Подразумеваем, что сотрудники честные) Делаете копию всего кода, восстанавливаете сервер из бэкапа, потом через *git diff* ловите подсадную утку в дырявом PHP скриптинге...

Comment: Вопрос закрыт.
По очереди вырубал все скрипты крона и нашел один из них содержащий инструкцию на запуск обфусцированного файла.